# How to read edge labels like "01, 1" on a state diagram?

Tags: terminology, automata, finite-automata

[image]

Is this state machine a moore machine or a mealy machine? I am confused because the states have outputs and the transitions have output based on the input. I tried making a state table but I think its wrong. Can anyone provide the state machine?

Comment: I'm a little baffled by the state machine.  I don't think the intention is that the transitions have outputs.  Rather I think that some edges take two different inputs.  But there is something wrong with the edge from C to D (is it really supposed to be a transition on 01 twice, or was it supposed to be a transition on either 10 or 01?)  Or maybe there's something else I don't understand.

Comment: @WanderingLogic well I'm glad im not the only one confused about the diagram

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of machine the term "state machine" asks for. In your table, note the gaps; you should probably not have these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the states define the output, it's a Moore machine.

The edge labels can be understood as follows: an edge $A \xrightarrow{w_1, \dots, w_k} B$ with $w \in \Sigma^*$ means that you can transition from $A$ to $B$ reading any of the *words* $w_1, \dots, w_k$.

Essentially, it's just a way to compact automata. As an exercise, you can expand the edges and see what you get. It's clear that this compactification is valid for finite automata, even if you add output (if you allow state output $\varepsilon$).

Comment: thank you. so the arrow that has "0, 10" is a short notation for writing "00 or 01 or 10" ?

Comment: @user14864 I would read that as "consume only 0". Some transitions consume one, others two symbols -- not a problem.